# Interactive Labeling of Images

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, dynamic

I have a list of pictures:

```
pictures = {im1,im2,im3,im4,im5,im6}
```

Where

im1:
[image]

im2:
[image]

im3:
[image]

im4:
[image]

im5:
[image]

im6:
[image]

I want to assign the pictures to labels (1,2,3,4,5 etc.). The pictures are already ordered according to their label. What I still need to do is to define the range of the labels.

For instance, here pictures 1 to 3 belong to label 1, picture 4 belongs to label 2, picture 5 to label 3, and picture 6 to label 4.

-> `label = {1,1,1,2,3,4}`

Since I need to see the images when I label them, I need a method to do that while labeling them. I was thinking of creating an array of images:

[image]

And then I define the ranges by clicking on the first and last picture belonging to the same labels, so for example:

[image]

**What do you think ? Is this somehow possible ?**

EDIT: Thank you all very much for the great answers. However, I think that I might have been not clear enough with the description of my question: I would like to assign different labels to different ranges of pictures.

[image]

For instance: When one has finished selecting the first label one could indicate it by a **Double-click**  and then do the selection of the second label range, then **Double-click**, then do the selection of the third label range, then **Double-click**, then do the selection of the fourth label range, etc.

It does not have to be Double-clicking to change the selection of the labels, it could also just be a buttom or any other idea that you might have.

In the end one should have the list of labels.

EDIT: This is what I have implemented so far (using the accepted answer):

```
m = 1;
n = 20;
i = 0;
labels = {};
{beginSelect, endSelect} = {0, 0};

selectImage[id_] := 
 If[beginSelect == 0, beginSelect = id, 
  endSelect = Max[beginSelect, id]]

makeImage[img_, False] := 
 Show[ImagePad[img, 5, White], ImageSize -> 100]
makeImage[img_, True] := Show[ImagePad[img, 5, Red], ImageSize -> 100]

addEventHandler[img_, id_] := 
 EventHandler[
  MouseAppearance[img, 
   "LinkHand"], {"MouseClicked" :> selectImage[id]}]

displayImages[imgs_] := 
 Grid[Partition[
   MapThread[
    addEventHandler[
      makeImage[#, 
       beginSelect <= #2 && #2 <= endSelect], #2] &, {imgs, 
     Range@Length@imgs}], 5]]


Dynamic[Deploy@Column[{displayImages[imgs[[m ;; n]]],
    Button["Next", If[m <= Length[imgs], {n = n + 5, m = m + 5}]],
    Button["New Label", 
     AppendTo[labels, i -> Range[beginSelect, endSelect]]; i++; 
     beginSelect = 0; endSelect = 0 ],
    Button["Back", If[n - 5 >= 1, {n = n - 5, m = m - 5} ]]}], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {beginSelect, endSelect, m, n}]
```

UPDATE 2:

```
Dynamic[Deploy@Column[{displayImages[imgs[[m ;; n]]],
    Button["Next", 
     If[m <= Length[imgs], {n = n + 5, m = m + 5}; 
      beginSelect = beginSelect - 5; endSelect = endSelect - 5]],
    Button["New Label", 
     AppendTo[labels, Table[i, {j, 1, (endSelect - beginSelect)}]]; 
     i++; beginSelect = endSelect + 1; endSelect = endSelect + 2],
    Button["Back", If[n - 5 >= 1, {n = n - 5, m = m - 5} ]]}], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {beginSelect, endSelect, m, n}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another version:

```
imgs = Flatten@ConstantArray[ConformImages[{
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cML6z.jpg"],
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EVAP.jpg"],
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAxUw.jpg"],
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fhan.jpg"],
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMXn5.jpg"],
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFBfM.jpg"]
      }], 2];

{beginSelect, endSelect} = {0, 0};
selectImage[id_] := If[beginSelect == 0, beginSelect = id, endSelect = Max[beginSelect, id]]

makeImage[img_, False] := Show[ImagePad[img, 5, White], ImageSize -> 200]
makeImage[img_, True] := Show[ImagePad[img, 5, Red], ImageSize -> 200]

addEventHandler[img_, id_] := EventHandler[
  MouseAppearance[img, "LinkHand"], {
   "MouseClicked" :> selectImage[id]
   }]

displayImages[imgs_] := Grid[Partition[MapThread[
    addEventHandler[
      makeImage[#, beginSelect <= #2 && #2 <= endSelect], #2] &, {
     imgs, Range@Length@imgs
     }], 3]]

Dynamic[Deploy@Column[{
    displayImages[imgs],
    Button["Reset", {beginSelect, endSelect} = {0, 0}]
    }], TrackedSymbols :> {beginSelect, endSelect}]
```

[image: Demo]

You can change the upper limit by selecting a new image that is larger than the lower limit. If you want to change the lower limit then you have to reset and start again. You can modify the reset button to e.g. write `beginSelect` and `endSelect` to file, or whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Looks very nice !! I really like the reset button and the  nice graphic layout ! Do you think that you could implement multi-labeling (explained in my updated question) ?

Comment: @james I think you should be able to do that yourself, as I've said it's a matter of modifying the reset button. For example, you could create a list `labels = {}` and a counter `i = 0` and then when the reset button is pressed you could run `AppendTo[labels, i -> Range[beginSelect, endSelect]]; i++`. Now, every time you push the button you add that set of images to a group in the `labels` variable. Please try, and if you have specific questions about difficulties then I will be happy to help. You could use `EventHandler` to do this with the keyboard instead of a button if you prefer that.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your suggestion ! I will try it :)

Comment: I have tried to implement it. Please see updated answer. I have a lot of images, so to easily view them, I show a grid of smaller height than all the images and by pushing "next" I can move up the images by 1 row, and by pushing "back", I move the images back down. Now I have two questions: 1. When I click on new label, I want the next image in the row next to the last selected image to be automatically the first selected image for the next labeling task. I don't understand how to implement that. It would be important such that I don't miss any image.

Comment: 2. I would like to have the images that have already been labeled to turn black and white or change color, anything... 

Thank you so much !

Comment: @james Have you tried setting `beginSelect` to `endSelect + 1` and `endSelect` to `endSelect + 2`, instead of setting them to zero? It seems like that could work. For the second question, just add a new definition to `makeImage` and then edit `beginSelect <= #2 && #2 <= endSelect` accordingly. You'll want to return a third value (not `True` or `False`) when `#2 < beginSelect`.

Comment: Yes, I have actually tried that. The problem is, that if click on "Next" to move down a row,  the selection does not move up also. Hence the wrong first image is selected. Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: beginSelect and endSelect somehow has to run from 1 to Length(imgs)  d and not just the images shown in the smaller grid imgs[[n;;m]]

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, but it's not beautiful. See update 2. Any improvements are welcomed.

Comment: @james You got it to work, that is the main thing! Elegance comes with practice like this. I'll just comment on a small thing... `Table[i, {j, 1, endSelect - beginSelect}]` can be written `Table[i, endSelect - beginSelect]`, but it would be even more semantic to write `ConstantArray[i, endSelect - beginSelect]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a beginning :

```
imageList=Take[Flatten[ImagePartition[ExampleData[{"TestImage","House"}],{50,50}]],7];

Table[
   With[{i=i},
   Button[
   Dynamic[If[i===start || i===stop || (NumericQ[start] && NumericQ[stop] && start <= i <= stop), Framed[#,Background->Red], #]& @ imageList[[i]]],
   If[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]===True,stop=i,start=i]
   ]],
{i,1,Length[imageList]}]
```

Left-click on the first image of the sequence you want to select.
Shift-left-click on the last image.

The variables `start`and `stop` get the indexes of the selection.

[image]

Of course, you can apply `Row`, `Column`, `MultiColumn`... on the list of button-images above and the buttons will still work.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is very nice, but can you also include multi-label selection as described in the updated question ?